# Why EF Core commits one transaction twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, transactions, ef-core-3.1

I have a very simple `ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API` that uses `PostgreSQL`. I want to log every command and transaction coming from EF Core. Julie Lerman wrote about logging SQL in EF Core in one of her columns - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/october/data-points-logging-sql-and-change-tracking-events-in-ef-core).

The problem I have is... it looks like EF Core starts **ONE** transaction, but then calls `Committing transaction` two times in a row? But.. why?

Here is the log:

```
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction[20209]
      Beginning transaction with isolation level 'Unspecified'.
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction[20200]
      Began transaction with isolation level 'ReadCommitted'.
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20103]
      Creating DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader'.
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20104]
      Created DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader' (4ms).
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@p0='?', @p1='?', @p2='?' (DbType = DateTime), @p3='?', @p4='?' (DbType = Int32), @p5='?', @p6='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "Users" ("BirthCity", "BirthCountry", "Birthday", "FirstName", "Height", "LastName", "Weight")
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6)
      RETURNING "UserId";
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20300]
      A data reader was disposed.
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction[20210]
      Committing transaction.
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction[20202]
      Committing transaction.
dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction[20204]
      Disposing transaction.
```

Here is the code:

**Startup class:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public static readonly ILoggerFactory SqlCommandAndTransactionLoggerFactory
        = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddFilter((category, level) =>
            ((category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name && level == LogLevel.Debug)
            || category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Transaction.Name && level == LogLevel.Debug))
            .AddConsole();
    });

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestDbContext");
        services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseNpgsql(connectionString)
                .UseLoggerFactory(SqlCommandAndTransactionLoggerFactory);
        });
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
    public User Add(User model)
    {
        _context.Users.Add(model);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return model;
    }
```

**Service:**

```
    public UserOutput Add(UserInput input)
    {
        var model = _mapper.Map<User>(input);
        var addedModel = _userRepository.Add(model);
        var output = _mapper.Map<UserOutput>(addedModel);
        return output;
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add([FromBody] UserInput userInput)
    {
        var userOutput = _userService.Add(userInput);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser", new { userId = userOutput.UserId }, userOutput);
    }
```

I simply created a factory, that will log every command and transaction. But here is the confusing part: It looks like it starts ONE transaction:

`Beginning transaction with isolation level 'Unspecified'`

`Began transaction with isolation level 'ReadCommitted'.`

... and then calls `Committing transaction` twice.

Comment: Can you please share with us your insert logic as well?

Comment: @PeterCsala just did.

Comment: How is your `DbContext` registered into the DI?

Comment: @PeterCsala I edited my question. Btw. `DbContext` in registered by using built-in IoC in the Startup class.

Comment: Ohh I can see it, you have used `AddDbContext` with default lifecycle (**scoped**). I would encourage you to register it as **Transient** or use the `AddDbContextPool` instead.

Comment: It's a bug, fixed here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/20861. It should be Committing transaction, Committed transaction